# Table header does not remains fixed though used position:absolute

Tags: html, css

I am trying a table header -  to remain fixed while the rows underneath -  should be able to scroll. After trying position:absolute to  it messes my headers width in table. Surely i am missing something, and i am new to CSS, so its what making it more tough.

*Also i do not want horizontal scroll, content must fit in given width 
(Responsive), due to that increasing in height of row is bearable*

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2g72e59k/)

**html**

```
<span class="d-body">
  <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox"/></th>
            <th> Date </th>
            <th> Category </th>
            <th> Details </th>
            <th> Amount </th>
            <th> Action </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td> 09-05-2015 </td>
            <td> Household Shopping </td>
            <td> Blah Blah........................................................................................... </td>
            <td> 9999 </td>
            <td> Edit </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td> 09-05-2015 </td>
            <td> Household Shopping </td>
            <td> Blah Blah........................................................................................... </td>
            <td> 9999 </td>
            <td> Edit </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td> 09-05-2015 </td>
            <td> Household Shopping </td>
            <td> Blah Blah........................................................................................... </td>
            <td> 9999 </td>
            <td> Edit </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td> 09-05-2015 </td>
            <td> Household Shopping </td>
            <td> Blah Blah........................................................................................... </td>
            <td> 9999 </td>
            <td> Edit </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td> 09-05-2015 </td>
            <td> Household Shopping </td>
            <td> Blah Blah........................................................................................... </td>
            <td> 9999 </td>
            <td> Edit </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td> 09-05-2015 </td>
            <td> Household Shopping </td>
            <td> Blah Blah........................................................................................... </td>
            <td> 9999 </td>
            <td> Edit </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td> 09-05-2015 </td>
            <td> Household Shopping </td>
            <td> Blah Blah........................................................................................... </td>
            <td> 9999 </td>
            <td> Edit </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td> 09-05-2015 </td>
            <td> Household Shopping </td>
            <td> Blah Blah.................................................................................................................. </td>
            <td> 9999 </td>
            <td> Edit </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
</span>
```

**css**

```
.d-body {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    max-height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
    background:#e6e6e6;
}
.d-body table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:100%;
}

.d-body thead tr {
    border-bottom:2px solid #2b2937;
    width:100%;
    background:#EDEDED;
}
.d-body thead tr:nth-child(1) {
    background:#009A9C;
    margin:0;
    color:#f2f2f2;
}

.d-body th, .d-body td {
    padding:10px 5px;
    text-align:left;
}

.d-body table thead {
    /*position:absolute;*/
    z-index:2;
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Sorry - I realised too late that the widths were collapsing so I've reworked my answer to address that issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no in solution for this in-built in HTML or CSS.  suggest you to make to tables one for the data and one for the headers. and change the size of cells according to the 2nd table.

Also you can try some other frameworks available on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I see the only way of maintaining the th widths is adding spans within them which will have the width of the parents applied and take those position fixed. Hide of the theader and add another element to spoof it which will also be position fixed.

http://jsfiddle.net/ntk8a7tt/

HTML

```
<span class="d-body">
    <span class="th-bg"></span>
<table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><span><input type="checkbox"/></span></th>
            <th><span>Date</span></th>
            <th><span>Category</span></th>
            <th><span>Details</span></th>
            <th><span>Amount</span></th>
            <th><span>Action</span></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td> 09-05-2015 </td>
            <td> Household Shopping </td>
            <td> Blah Blah........................................................................................... </td>
            <td> 9999 </td>
            <td> Edit </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td> 09-05-2015 </td>
            <td> Household Shopping </td>
            <td> Blah Blah........................................................................................... </td>
            <td> 9999 </td>
            <td> Edit </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td> 09-05-2015 </td>
            <td> Household Shopping </td>
            <td> Blah Blah........................................................................................... </td>
            <td> 9999 </td>
            <td> Edit </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td> 09-05-2015 </td>
            <td> Household Shopping </td>
            <td> Blah Blah........................................................................................... </td>
            <td> 9999 </td>
            <td> Edit </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td> 09-05-2015 </td>
            <td> Household Shopping </td>
            <td> Blah Blah........................................................................................... </td>
            <td> 9999 </td>
            <td> Edit </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td> 09-05-2015 </td>
            <td> Household Shopping </td>
            <td> Blah Blah........................................................................................... </td>
            <td> 9999 </td>
            <td> Edit </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td> 09-05-2015 </td>
            <td> Household Shopping </td>
            <td> Blah Blah........................................................................................... </td>
            <td> 9999 </td>
            <td> Edit </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td> 09-05-2015 </td>
            <td> Household Shopping </td>
            <td> Blah Blah.................................................................................................................. </td>
            <td> 9999 </td>
            <td> Edit </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
</span>
```

CSS

```
.d-body {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    max-height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
    background:#e6e6e6;
}
.d-body table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 2.4em;
}
.d-body input[type=checkbox] {
    transform:scale(1.18);
}
.d-body thead tr {
    width:100%;
    background:#EDEDED;
}
.d-body thead tr:nth-child(1) {
    margin:0;
    color:#f2f2f2;
}
.d-body th, .d-body td {
    padding:10px 5px;
    text-align:left;
}
.d-body tr:hover {
    background:#ddd;
}
.d-body th {
    padding: 0;
}
.d-body table thead tr {
    height: 1px;
}
tr span {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -1.6em;
z-index: 11;

}
.th-bg {
    height: 2.4em;
    position: fixed;
    background:#009A9C;
    display: block;
    width: 10   .d-body {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    max-height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
    background:#e6e6e6;
}
.d-body table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 2.4em;
}
.d-body input[type=checkbox] {
    transform:scale(1.18);
}
.d-body thead tr {
    width:100%;
    background:#EDEDED;
}
.d-body thead tr:nth-child(1) {
    margin:0;
    color:#f2f2f2;
}
.d-body th, .d-body td {
    padding:10px 5px;
    text-align:left;
}
.d-body tr:hover {
    background:#ddd;
}
.d-body th {
    padding: 0;
}
.d-body table thead tr {
    height: 1px;
}
tr span {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -1.6em;
z-index: 11;

}
.th-bg {
    height: 2.4em;
    position: fixed;
    background:#009A9C;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    border-bottom:2px solid #2b2937;
}
0%;
    z-index: 10;
    border-bottom:2px solid #2b2937;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is of no use as the columns of table header </thead> and table rows <tbody> are not following the format.

Comment: @divy3993 I realised that was of no use so I've completely revised the answer and hope this one helps.

Answer (score 0):

just add `.header-1` class in your first `tr`

i put `.header-1` class css below :

```
    .header-1
    {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;

    }
```

i hope its work for you

demo :[jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/2g72e59k/2/)